# Using connect and mapDispatchToProps with asynchronous calls

Tags: reactjs, redux

Consider the following example, and imagine the component is rendering based on the state of blogs:

```
class BlogList extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        getBlogPosts()
            .then(blogs => this.props.dispatch({
                type: 'LOAD_BLOGS',
                blogs
            }))
    }
}
```

getBlogPosts calls an api, which returns a list of relevent blog posts. I would like to then update the redux store with the results of this call. The preceding code does this successfully, but I would like to pull this out into a mapDispatchToProps param to connect(), something like:

```
const mapDispatchToBlogListProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        loadBlogs: getBlogPosts()
                    .then(blogs => dispatch({
                        type: 'LOAD_BLOGS',
                        blogs
                    }))
    }
};

const VisibleBlogList = connect(
    mapStateToBlogListProps,
    mapDispatchToBlogListProps
)(BlogList);

class BlogList extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadBlogs()
    }
}
```

Is this good practice? Is there a better way? Can/should I use promises in the mapDispatch function?

Answer (score 0):

The idea you're getting at is pretty common and you have to do something like this in order to handle requesting resources. I would suggest checking out the [redux-thunk middleware](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) though. You'll be able to handle your example and more complicated flows as well.

You'll likely soon run into cases where you need have multiple dispatches; for instance, you may need dispatch a loading action before a request, a success action if the request succeeds, and a fail action if the request returned in error, since all of these cases could affect your ui.